# How can I add spacing around the HTML5 time input element?

Tags: css, html

I tried this:

```
input[time] {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

...but it does nothing.

Just to see what, if anything would happen, I also added parring: 2px; but still nothing. So how can I get the time element to shove other elements that invade its personal space out of the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify it is a type like so

```
input[type="time"]{
    margin: 2px;
}
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/styling-texty-inputs-only/) goes other this further if you are interested,

Kieran

Answer (score 1):

Use `input[type="time"]` instead of `input[time]`

The `[attribute]` CSS selector targets HTML tags who have a certain attribute no matter the attribute's value.

The `[attribute="value"]` CSS selector targets HTML tags with an attribute with a set value.